# Occipital (RGB-D sensor like Kinect) on Parrot AR. DRONE using SLAM algorithm

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm using Occipital (RGB-D sensor like Kinect) on Parrot AR. DRONE for navigation using SLAM algorithm.... What do I do for obstacle avoidance, is it done by the SLAM or should I use additional sensors If I use additional sensors, how do I make it a part of the SLAM algorithm.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173607/occipital-(rgb-d-sensor-like-kinect)-on-parrot-ar.-drone-using-slam-algorithm/) by [Francis Dom](https://answers.ros.org/users/18829/francis-dom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-06-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Occipital "Structure Sensor" looks like an overpriced version of the Kinect or Xtion sensor. It's only selling point seems to be a much smaller size, but it appears to uses the same technology as Kinect/Xtion, so based on [this page](http://www.ros.org/news/2014/04/occipital-committed-to-support-openni.html), it might work with the same code/packages for those sensors that use the OpenNI driver. I haven't used them though, so I can't say for sure if they'll work.

---

Originally posted by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) with karma: 940 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0